# Tomcat - URL without ports and without using port 80/443

Tags: windows, tomcat

the system is Server 2008 R2 and it uses about 20 Tomcats that are set as services. It is set like this:

App-name: myapp

Port: 8085 (the range of all 20 Tomcats is from 8080 up to 8099 for the 20th Tomcat)

URL: mycomputer.mydomain.com/myapp instead of mycomputer/mydomain.com:8085/myapp

So it is not requiring the port in the URL and the port is not 80. I wasn't the one who set this up and I cannot figure out how to reproduce it with other Tomcats that I want to install. The guy who set this up is not among our company anymore, so I cannot ask him. I tried googling for help, but I somehow just get links where people are being told to change the port to 80 which is not helpful.

Thanks in advance. English isn't my first language so I might be chosing wrong/bad terms trying to look for help on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install web server (like nginx) and use it to proxy for your Tomcats.
for example (nginx):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mycomputer.mydomain.com;
  location /myapp {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8085;
  }
  location /myapp2 {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8086;
  }
  .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I found the solution on my end too. I overlooked that he had Xampp installed on that machine too.

They are all in this file:
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ajp.conf